# Unknown type name 'NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN' in NSZone.h

Tags: ios, frameworks, ios-simulator, foundation, xcode11.5

I am trying to build a Framework and make it run in iOS Simulator. It builds fine with No Custom Frameworks added to it. I am adding a Framework via CocoaPods and it starts throwing **Semantic Issues and Parse Issues** errors related to **Foundation Framework**. No idea about all the errors coming.

Attaching the Image with the errors for reference.

[image]

> /Applications/Xcode_11.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:11:1:
> **Unknown type name '**NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN**'**

> /Applications/Xcode_11.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:15:1: **Unknown type name '**FOUNDATION_EXPORT**'**

> /Applications/Xcode_11.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:17:38: **Unknown type name '**NSZone**'**

Everything works fine in the device but my primary objective is to build the Framework and make it run in iOS Simulator. I am using **Xcode 11.5** and **iOS 13.5**. Got struck on this badly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only correct solution i found after banging my head is to Uninstall and Install a New Xcode Version. Don't look further than this and search for a different solution. It would be a time waste effort. Just Uninstall and re-install the Xcode will do. **I kept searching for a solution for about 4-5 days but only Uninstalling and Re-Installing new xcode version worked at the end.**

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem, reason due to the corrupted Foundation framework
Fixed by replacing Foundation framework
from other working xcode.app
in the following path with/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework.